# Can't find my string in target using strpos

Tags: php

$cartArray structure:

```
Array ( [0] => 1. X => 2. Y [2] => 3. Z [3] => 4. XX [4] => 5. YY [5] => )
```

$list:

```
$list = array(
    "1.",
    "2.",
    "3.",
    "4.",
    "5."
);
```

Function

```
function alignNum($cartArray, $list)
{
   foreach($cartArray as $cA)
   {
      echo "<br />" . $cA . "<br /><br />";
      foreach($list as $l)
      {
            echo $l . "<br />";
            echo "Type of \$l is " . gettype($l) . " and type of \$cA is " . gettype($cA) . "<br />";

            $pos = strpos($cA, $l);

            echo "Comparing " . $l . " to " . $cA . "<br />";

            if ($pos !== true)
            {
                echo "<br />" . $l . " was not found in " . $cA . "<br /><br />";
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                $post_cA = str_replace("EUR", "EUR</span>", $cA);

                $new_cA[] = (str_replace($l, substr($l, 0, -4) . "<span style='float: right>'", $cA)) . $post_cA;

                return $new_cA;
            }


          }
      }
}

$new_cart = alignNum($cart, $list);
```

So, I keep getting my custom debug message: "X was not found in Y". I.e it's not founding it X in ANY of the provided strings.

It's not a question of types either. Both are strings.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Also, note that I've censored some stuff out, since this is business related code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea (unless you are C programmer) to compare numeric and boolean even in
`if ($pos != true)`
but in
`if ($pos !== true)`
AFAIK it will NEVER match because the variables are different types

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry, but how is that relevant? Don't want to come off as rude, but I mentioned in my post that both variables are strings.

Comment: @user1308765 imagine that you match it at position 0 and when you compare it to bool it (pos = 0) will be implicitly casted to false and you will be with result that it doesnt exist but it actually matches.

Comment: OK, it is relevant, but my assumption that PHP call to strpos() will return consistent result type was incorrect. See Jojo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

German Arlington is actually right.
Have a look what [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) is returning:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

with

```
if ($pos !== true)
```

you are asking wether strpos returned a boolean true (as you are checking typesafe with !==).
But actually strpos may have found the needle and returned i.e 2 for the position of the first match, but you asked for true.

try to check the other way round:

```
if (false === $pos) { // your debug message }
```

Comment: This is one of (many) reasons why I don't like PHP: why does the function that should return NUMERIC value suddenly return FALSE???

Comment: I wont start the PHP love/hate thing here, life´s to short... more important related to the question is that strpos will NEVER return a boolean true ;)

Comment: if I do execute your function now with my fix and your given values I do not get your errormessage. Instead your str_replace stuff is executed. So it is definitly another problem you`re facing now. please update your question therefor, as "does not work" is not saying anything